# What is a unit increase in logistic regression on standardized data?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am confused about the unit increase on a dataset that has been standardized to have mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1. E.g. the temperature went from 0 to 100 deg initially, and from -1.5 top 1.5 after standardization.
What does the unit increase mean in coefficient analysis for logistic regression now? Is this unit still one unit in the non-standardized data, such as temperature goes from 99 to 100, or is it some relative measure, such as temperature goes from -1.5 to -0.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unit is now a one standard deviation change. If you have variables with a known unit, like temperature, you are better of not standardizing, as you make the unit harder to interpret.

Comment: To add to this response: if there is a compelling reason to standardize your predictors prior to fitting the model, e.g. penalized likelihood, you can always *un*standardize the resulting coefficient estimates by dividing them by the standard deviation of the corresponding predictor. Then your estimated coefficients can be interpreted on the natural scale.

Comment: I see, thank you very much Maarten and psboonstra, I will unstandardize the resulting coefficients in that case!